# The str_replace method does not work in php

Tags: php, str-replace

I use str_replace and does not work properly.
I have a QueryString I want to replace some of the words with the amount of input, but the str_replace method does not work and does not change anything.

```
$inputdata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$query2 = $inputdata["QueryString"] . $where . " ORDER BY "  .$inputdata["DataRequest"]["Sort"][0]["field"]." " .$inputdata["DataRequest"]["Sort"][0]["dir"]. " LIMIT ".$inputdata["DataRequest"][take]." OFFSET " .$inputdata["DataRequest"][offset];
for ($x = 0; $x < count($parameters); $x++) {

 $query2 = str_replace($inputdata["parameters"][$x][key],$inputdata["parameters"][$x][value],$query2);

}
```

`query2`return :

> " SELECT `Members`.*, `HouseholdAdmin`.`AdminCode` FROM `Members` JOIN `HouseholdAdmin`  ON Members.HouseholdAdminId=HouseholdAdmin.HouseholdAdminId WHERE MemberId =%MemberId   "

`str_replace($inputdata["parameters"][$x][key],$inputdata["parameters"][$x][value],$query2);` not work

`$query2 = str_replace('%MemberId','2',$query2);` not work.

`$query2 = str_replace('SELECT','dsdfsdfsdf',$query2);` not work.

`$query2 = str_replace('anyThing','anyThing',$query2);` not work.

,....

It does not matter which words I enter & replace in str_replace, nothing works.

Comment: I think you should completely re-write this flawed and terribly insecure attempt at creating SQL statements. Can you show what your input data looks like, and what final query you need?

Comment: `str_replace` does not manipulate the parameter you feed to it, it _returns_ the modified value.

Comment: My friend, you should have read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php first before posting question here, just google search for "str_replace" will give you manual as first result. 

And in description first sentence says: "This function **returns** a string or an array with all occurrences of search in subject replaced with the given replace value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query2 = str_replace($inputdata["parameters"][$x][key],$inputdata["parameters"][$x][key],$query2); 

$query2 = str_replace('%MemberId','2',$query2); 

$query2 = str_replace('SELECT','dsdfsdfsdf',$query2);

$query2 = str_replace('anyThing','anyThing',$query2);
```